# transform.Translate seems to accelerate and decelerate object when reading from Input.GetAxis()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started using Unity recently and I have a very simple script shown below which moves a sprite left, right, up and down.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

  // Speed set to 5 in Inspector
  public int speed;

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {
    var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speed;
    var y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * speed;

    transform.Translate (x, y, 0);
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I press the an arrow key, the sprite seems to accelerate for a second or less and when I release the key it seems to decelerate for a second or less. I do not want it to do that, I just want it to have the same speed all of the time without any acceleration or deceleration.

Can you please let me know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `Debug.Log()` to determine whether your horizontal/vertical values are a consistent value (they should be, since you're using arrow keys, but just to make sure).

Comment: @Serlite X and Y values are always below 0.1 but not consistent, they change all of the time

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out by looking at the API.

Input.GetAxis seems to apply a smoothing filter. I found this out or deduced it when I saw the Input.GetAxisRaw function, in its description it says

> Returns the value of the virtual axis identified by axisName with no smoothing filtering applied.

Which leads me to believe the Input.GetAxis function applies smoothing.

So the function now reads

```
void Update () {
    var x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speed;
    var y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * speed;

    transform.Translate (x, y, 0);
}
```

Thank you all for your time

Regards
Crouz

Comment: Good find! Guess sometimes it helps to just take another look at the docs.

Comment: Small note - don't forget that you can accept your own answer, which will mark this question to others as successfully solved.